# Mac OS keeps switching to the first desktop Please Help Me

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, catalina, mission-control

mac:MacBookPro 2019
system:Catalina 10.15.7

When I running full screen software,My screen keeps jumping to the first "desktop". This happens at random.

I didn't install “Google Drive”

Comment: Is it switching the frontmost app? Do you have any app in more than one Space?

Comment: Thanks bro ,I've been updated Big Sur ，I hope it doesn't exist anymore

Comment: Problems will still after the upgrade.. 
Even if there is no app in the first space